# Spring MVC Controller, how to keep BindingResult errors, while emptying the form values

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a web form, using Spring MVC Controller. The form is validated by Spring.
When there are validation errors, Spring shows the same form, pre-filled in with the values entered by the user, and the validation errors.

For security reasons, I don't want the form the be pre-filled with the values entered by the user, but I do need to show the validation errors.

How can I do this?

I've achieved this behaviour by looking at the Spring MVC source code and seeing how the BINDING_RESULT_KEY is built. Here it is the source code.

However, this is a hack, and it might stop working on a new version of Spring MVC.

How do I achieve this properly?

```
package com.nespresso.ecommerce.naw.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ObjectError;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.validation.Valid;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/my_form")
public class MyFormController extends FrontEndController {
    final String MY_FORM_OBJECT_NAME = "myForm";
    final String BINDING_RESULT_KEY = BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "myForm";

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String post(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm myForm, Errors errors, Model model) {
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            emptyMyFormWhileKeepingFormErrors(model);
            return "my_form";
        }

        return "redirect:/confirmation";
    }

    @ModelAttribute("myForm")
    public MyForm myForm() {
        return new MyForm();
    }

    private void emptyMyFormWhileKeepingFormErrors(Model model) {
        BeanPropertyBindingResult bindingResult = (BeanPropertyBindingResult) model.asMap().get(BINDING_RESULT_KEY);
        if (bindingResult == null) {
            return;
        }
        MyForm emptyForm = myForm();

        // set the empty form, so the form is not pre-filled with the previous values.
        // However, this clears the validation errors also
        model.addAttribute(MY_FORM_OBJECT_NAME, emptyForm);

        // re-attach the validation errors, and empty the rejectedValue
        BeanPropertyBindingResult updatedBindingResult = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(emptyForm, MY_FORM_OBJECT_NAME);
        for (ObjectError oe : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
            if (!(oe instanceof FieldError)) {
                updatedBindingResult.addError(oe);
            } else {
                FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) oe;

                String rejectedValue = null;   // that's the point, create a copy of the FieldError, emptying the rejectedValue;

                FieldError updatedFieldError = new FieldError(
                        MY_FORM_OBJECT_NAME,
                        fieldError.getField(),
                        rejectedValue,
                        fieldError.isBindingFailure(),
                        fieldError.getCodes(),
                        fieldError.getArguments(),
                        fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
                updatedBindingResult.addError(updatedFieldError);
            }
        }

        model.addAttribute(BINDING_RESULT_KEY, updatedBindingResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Either you are using `<form:*>` tags to show values on your model (and values rejected during parameter binding) and validation errors or you are using plain `<input>` with `<form:errors>` tag. There is no other way.

Comment: *"For security reasons"* - can you share your security concerns? You might be *overthinking* something.

Comment: Pavel, good point. I am using thymeleaf `<input th:field="*{companyName}"/>` tag, which gets expanded to `<input id="compayName" name="companyName" th:value="*{companyName}"/>`. so, i should just change to `<input name="companyName"/>`. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/thymeleafspring.html#inputs
However, this is not java code, so how can then unit test that values are not shown?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit : add another solution

You can have an empty model object while keeping previous errors simply by copying fresh values (from a newly initialized object) into your model attribute via `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils`:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String post(@Valid @ModelAttribute("myForm") MyForm myForm, Errors errors, Model model) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        MyForm emptyForm = new MyForm();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(emptyForm, myForm);
        return "my_form";
    }

    return "redirect:/confirmation";
}
```

That way, you can still show previous errors, and the form is empty.

There is still a caveat : if works fine when I use `<input>` fields, but not with `<form:input>` spring enhanced fields that do use the rejected value from `errors`.

If you prefere to keep using `<form:input>` fields, you will have to create another `BindingResult` object and initialize it with current errors, simply setting the rejected values to null. You have even the possibility to reset all fields or only the fields in error :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String update(@Valid @ModelAttribute Form form, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        // uncomment line below to reset all fields - by default only offending ones are
        //form = new Form();
        BeanPropertyBindingResult result2 = new BeanPropertyBindingResult(form, result.getObjectName());
        for(ObjectError error: result.getGlobalErrors()) {
            result2.addError(error);
        }
        for (FieldError error: result.getFieldErrors()) {
            result2.addError(new FieldError(error.getObjectName(), error.getField(), null, error.isBindingFailure(), error.getCodes(), error.getArguments(), error.getDefaultMessage()));
        }
        model.addAllAttributes(result2.getModel());
        return "my_form";
    }

    return "redirect:/confirmation";
}
```

Comment: this does not work, because the "errors" variable contains a list of FieldError's, and a FieldError has a rejectValue variable. so, if one of the fields didn't pass the validation, it shows the value for that field.

Comment: @DavidPortabella: I updated my post with another solution that allows use of `<form:input>`.

Comment: Ok, I see, the difference with the code i posted in the question is that you use errors.getObjectName() or result.getObjectName() to get the MY_FORM_OBJECT_NAME. good point, thx.

Comment: for a complete answer, see also the comment of Pavel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326591/spring-mvc-controller-how-to-keep-bindingresult-errors-while-emptying-the-form#comment39545167_25326591

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I can think of is to not use the `<form:*>` tags. Instead use a standard `<input>` tag.

**For example:**

```
<form:form modelAttribute="userForm" method="post">
    Username: <form:input path="username" /><br>

    <form:errors path="password" element="div" />
    Password: <input path="password" ><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form:form>
```

In the above example the password field will remain blank at all times while still showing the validation error.

Comment: that's a good point; but Pavel already gave this same answer in a comment to the question. i can award the bounty to only one person, so i'll award it to Serge, for he has also a valid solution.

Comment: What you do with the bounty is your decision but I wouldn't mark it as the accepted answer. Visitors seeking an answer to the same problem will be presented a over enginered solution to a simple problem :)